# Google Map showing blank screen with 'Google' logo bottom left

Tags: java, android, xml, google-maps-api-3

I have searched and searched and found many different solutions to this problem for different people but everything I have tried has not been successful in my case.

Basically I have added a Google Map and copied my SHA-1 fingerprint (double and triple checked it was correct) and pasted my API key into the Android Manifest (again double and triple checked that the key was correct).

When in the Google Development Console the graph shows spikes where I have been loading the map but never once have I been able to see anything other than a blank screen.

I have the Google Repository, Google Play Services, etc. all installed.

I have also added the permissions in the manifest and the dependencies in the build.gradle.

I had also created a new Google Maps Activity to automatically generate the /debug and /release folders and .xml files within /src/ and updated them with current and regenerated API keys. I've copied the link that is automatically generated to generate an API key with no luck.

Because the problem seems to be that the map won't load tells me that there must be a problem with the fingerprint or API key, but I am not sure what else to try.

I am running on the emulator at the minute and have tried once in an actual device with the same problem.

I am still fairly new to Android Studio and Java so it could more than likely be that the answer is sticking out like a sore thumb!

[Blank Map](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mQGkq.png)

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="assignment2.thebookmark">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <!-- Map API Key -->


        <!--
             The API key for Google Maps-based APIs is defined as a string resource.
             (See the file "res/values/google_maps_api.xml").
             Note that the API key is linked to the encryption key used to sign the APK.
             You need a different API key for each encryption key, including the release key that is used to
             sign the APK for publishing.
             You can define the keys for the debug and release targets in src/debug/ and src/release/. 
        -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
            android:value="@string/google_maps_key" />

        <activity
            android:name=".MapsActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_maps"></activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

fragment_contact.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp" />


</FrameLayout>
```

ContactFragment.java

```
package assignment2.thebookmark;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapsInitializer;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;

/**
 * Created by brandanmcdevitt on 26/04/2017.
 */

public class ContactFragment extends Fragment implements OnMapReadyCallback {

    GoogleMap mGoogleMap;
    MapView mMapView;
    View mView;

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        mView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_contact, container, false);

        return mView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

        mMapView = (MapView) mView.findViewById(R.id.map);
        if (mMapView != null) {
            mMapView.onCreate(null);
            mMapView.onResume();
            mMapView.getMapAsync(this);
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {

        MapsInitializer.initialize(getContext());
        mGoogleMap = googleMap;
        googleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NONE);

        LatLng headOffice = new LatLng(54.508460, -6.763554);

        googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(headOffice).title("The Reading Room").snippet("The Beginning of Your Next Adventure"));

        googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(headOffice));

    }
}
```

Edit, logcat

```
05-02 18:57:10.587 3507-3507/assignment2.thebookmark I/zzai: Making Creator dynamically
05-02 18:57:10.591 3507-3507/assignment2.thebookmark W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /system/priv-app/PrebuiltGmsCore/lib/x86
05-02 18:57:10.591 3507-3507/assignment2.thebookmark D/ApplicationLoaders: ignored Vulkan layer search path /system/priv-app/PrebuiltGmsCore/lib/x86:/system/fake-libs:/system/priv-app/PrebuiltGmsCore/PrebuiltGmsCore.apk!/lib/x86:/system/lib:/vendor/lib for namespace 0xb507d090
05-02 18:57:10.607 3507-3507/assignment2.thebookmark W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: 
05-02 18:57:10.607 3507-3507/assignment2.thebookmark W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /system/priv-app/PrebuiltGmsCore/lib/x86
05-02 18:57:10.608 3507-3507/assignment2.thebookmark D/ApplicationLoaders: ignored Vulkan layer search path /system/priv-app/PrebuiltGmsCore/lib/x86:/system/fake-libs:/system/priv-app/PrebuiltGmsCore/PrebuiltGmsCore.apk!/lib/x86:/system/lib:/vendor/lib for namespace 0xb507d0d0
05-02 18:57:10.615 3507-3507/assignment2.thebookmark W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: 

/data/user_de/0/com.google.android.gms/app_chimera/m/00000002/n/x86
05-02 18:57:10.645 3507-3507/assignment2.thebookmark I/Google Maps Android API: Google Play services client version: 10240000
05-02 18:57:10.662 3507-3507/assignment2.thebookmark I/Google Maps Android API: Google Play services package version: 10298470
05-02 18:57:10.822 3507-3673/assignment2.thebookmark D/NetworkSecurityConfig: No Network Security Config specified, using platform default

                                                                              [ 05-02 18:57:10.939  3507: 3698 D/         ]
                                                                              HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xabf1df40, tid 3698
05-02 18:57:10.984 3507-3507/assignment2.thebookmark 

W/IInputConnectionWrapper: finishComposingText on inactive InputConnection
05-02 18:57:12.913 3507-3700/assignment2.thebookmark W/DynamiteModule: Local module descriptor class for com.google.android.gms.googlecertificates not found.
05-02 18:57:12.928 3507-3700/assignment2.thebookmark I/DynamiteModule: Considering local module com.google.android.gms.googlecertificates:0 and remote module com.google.android.gms.googlecertificates:2
05-02 18:57:12.928 3507-3700/assignment2.thebookmark I/DynamiteModule: Selected remote version of com.google.android.gms.googlecertificates, version >= 2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I can see you are missing the most important permission:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Without it, your app isn't allowed to access the internet, thus it isn't able to download the map and it shows a white screen (as described by you) instead

---

As that doesn't work for you, try adding this:

```
<meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
    android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

Comment: Thanks, I just added it into the manifest but still showing the blank screen.

Comment: Try uninstalling (restarting the device if it doesn't delete the data) and reinstall

Comment: And make sure your device is connected to the internet

Comment: I'm running the emulator for testing, do you mean basically close the emulator and re-run? Internet is connected.

Comment: The emulator has internet if your computer does, and it isn't set to have no access. Just uninstall the app, basically

Comment: Unfortunately it Is still showing as blank after doing all this.

Comment: Open Logcat and see if there are any clues there